# node.js multer module can't handle errors

Tags: node.js, error-handling, multer

I have created a node.js server and i use the multer module for upload some files.
my problem is : how can i handle errors? like if the client close untile the upload is finished? sorry for bad english, i'm italian.
this is my actual don't working code :

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/root/appsistMe/public/AppMeFile/Utenti/'+req.session.nome);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage,
                onError : function(err, next) {
                console.log('error');
                next(err);
            }});

app.post('/uploadFile', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next){
    console.log("CI SIAMO AL DOWNLOADDDDDD");
    mongo.aggiungiNuovoFile(req, res);
    res.status(204).end();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onError` was removed in version `1.0.0` .

```
var upload = multer().single('avatar')

app.post('/profile', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // An error occurred when uploading
      return
   }

    // Everything went fine
  })
})
```

Please check [this link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling) for more details